# Wildcard String Selection MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select, wildcard

I have a table something like this

```
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|      Column 1                              |     column 2     |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_1                             |         10       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_1/                            |         15       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_1/sp1_level2                  |         10       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_1/sp1_level2/sp1_level3       |         20       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_2/                            |         25       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_2/sp2_level2/sp2_level3       |         20       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_3                             |         30       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
```

I want to use a select statement to select from column 1 and add values for column 2 that my resulting table is

```
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|      Column 1                              |     column 2     |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_1/                            |         55       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_2/                            |         45       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
|/fixed/sample_3/                            |         30       |
|--------------------------------------------|------------------|
```

Is there any way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `substring_index()` and `group by`:

```
select substring_index(col1, '/', 3) as new_col1,
       sum(col2)
from t
group by new_col1;
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct Gordon but I realized that GoogleSQL is not equivalent to MySQL and it doesn't have substring_index function. Any other way this can be done? thanks

Comment: @ManojAgrawal . . . I don't know what you mean by GoogleSQL.  If you mean BigQuery, then ask a new question and tag it with BigQuery.